# R stops subsetting when it gets to double digits

Tags: r, subset

First time here:

I need to subset based on data results being >4.9 (and it goes up to 22.2), but R stop subsetting at 9.8 and leaves out 10-22.2. 
My code:

```
rha.under.six.total.elevated<- rha.under.six.total[which(rha.under.six.total$lead_level>"4.9"),]
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Note that `4.9` is very different from `"4.9"` -- one is a numeric value and one is a character value. They have different rules for sorting.

Comment: I agree that your description stringly (pun intended) suggests that a column that you think is numbers is actually characters, but it's hard to say for sure without a more detailed example to work with.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
rha.under.six.total.elevated <- rha.under.six.total[rha.under.six.total$lead_level>4.9, ]
```

I think the `which()` statement is superfluous, you just need a "boolean" condition in order to filter rows. Then you don't need to represent the "4.9" as a character.

Comment: The `which()` can make a big difference if you have NA values.